# Is it possible to reload certain tab in node.js?

Tags: node.js, reload

I want to refresh a chosen tab in chrome via node, is it possible? All the solutions I've found so far apply to applications running in node through localhost, which is not what am I looking for.

Comment: The question is quite unclear, you want to reload the browser from the server? Do you have any code sample you tried (it helps to understand what you want).

Comment: application that needs to be reloaded is running on independent server, I want node app to listen for changes and refresh a certain tab on this event.  My solution so far is to use `browserSync({proxy: "hereGoesTheAdress"})` and then `browserSync.reload(); ` but I was wondering if there is maybe another way to do this.